# Swap IRS - SOFR lookback

Tags: interest-rate-swap, sofr, soft-question

I have a fixed-float swap valuation to realize. The floating leg is referenced to SOFR with a 10 days lookback. The first coupon has already started, on 01/09/2023, and ends on 01/12/2023. The first coupon fixing is realized on 15/11/2023.

How do I evaluate the first floating coupon interest rate if I want to evaluate the swap MtM on 01/09/2023 or on a later date? (i.e. before the first fixing is realized).

I understand that for later coupons I can evaluate the floating coupons rate with the help of forward rates (constructed from spot rates that I retrieve from my market data provider bloomberg (490 icvs curve)).

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: Just load it in SWPM and it will do all the work for you. You can set the lookback there. [This answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/69724/54838) explains how teh lookback is computed (vs the backward shift approach).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to compute the swap manually (to be sure I understand the number Bloomberg gives me).  Does this mean that to determine the swap MtM on 02/09/2023 (so before the first fixing date) I will have to compute a compound lookback for the first coupon ?  

Each coupon has a 3 months duration, so I was thinking to take the valuation date (02/09/2023) has a temporary fixing date and realize the compounding for 3 preceding months (and  taking into account the lookback)! 

Any guidance would be helpful, thanks !